# How to deal with this blindspot?

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around with typescript and can't figure out why typescript doesn't do type schecking in this particular case. `'this.a.method()'` should case an error, but everything transpiles just fine. I'd like typescript to tell me that `a.method()` requires `string` value as parameter. What am I missing?

```
class A {
  method(value: string){
    console.log(value);
  }
}
class B {
  constructor(private a){}
  call(){
    this.a.method()
  }
}
const a = new A();
const b = new B(a);
b.call();
```

Comment: Can you describe what you expect to happen in this case?

Comment: You can set `"noImplicitAny": true,` in your tsconfig.json so errors like these don't pass silently.

Comment: @Saravana, exactly what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying type for `private a;` in B's constructor.
It should read `constructor(private a: A){}`

```
class A {
  method(value: string){
    console.log(value);
  }
}
class B {
  constructor(private a: A){}
  call(){
    this.a.method()
  }
}
const a = new A();
const b = new B(a);
b.call();
```

Obviously, then you will have compilation error at `this.a.method()` as you need to pass a string as an argument: `this.a.method("foo")`.

Comment: yay! It works! Thank you good sir! Your answer will be accepted in 7 minutes!

Comment: one quick question though... how come in angular when I do the same thing typechecking works as expected. I mean, I do `constructor(private a){}` and everything is ok.

Comment: If the type is not specified it is considered to be `any`, saying 'don't give me errors' to the compiler. You can make an experiment by setting `"noImplicitAny": true` in your `tsconfig.json`, to detect all these cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the type for a variable or property, it is assumed to be of type `any`, and `any` effectively means `don't do type checking here`. It is different from type `object`. If you want typescript to do type checking, give your property `a` a type `constructor(private a: SomeType) { }`